# JS: Setting focus on DOM-element does not update document.activeElement

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'm currently trying to manually set focus on two buttons after each other. They are jQuery-Objects, saved in an array called pMenus. Here is the code

```
function OpenSubMenus(pMenus) {

    pMenus[pMenus.length - 1].get(0).focus();

    $(pMenus[pMenus.length - 1]).click();
    
    if (pMenus.length == 1) {
        return;
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        pMenus[pMenus.length - 1].get(0).blur();
        pMenus.pop();
        OpenSubMenus(pMenus);
    }, 1000)
}
```

The problem is, that on the second manual `.focus()`, the activeElement stays on the `body of the page`. Has anyone encountered that problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for bothering everyone. I did not provide enough information for you, as I should have mentioned, that the button to be focused was not not visible (`visibility: hidden`).

If the element is visible, the code mentioned in the question works.

Thanks for your help and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that  `pMenus[pMenus.length - 1]` returns second button not first. Use  `pMenus[pMenus.length - 2]` to get first element.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found the solution, as I didn't knew that the element needs to be visible to be focused. Thanks again.